# Accurate solution for completely unbalanced design (18 observations vs 500 observations)_need some advice

Tags: regression, linear

> I have a data set including one continuous dependent variable, one
>   categorical independent with 4 levels and one continuous independent
>   variable. We are going to compare the average of the dependent
>   variable among the levels of the categorical variable by adjusting the
>   covariate. The problem is there is a huge gap between the number of
>   the observations in each category of the categorical independent.
>   n1=17, n2=19, n3=400, n4=25. Now my question is the accuracy of
>   applying linear regression/ancova when we have this kind of design.?
>   Any advice? Can you recommend a method to do this kind of analysis?